# Xamarin Autocomplete view: Display dropdown even when there is no text

Tags: xamarin, autocompletetextview

I am implementing an autocomplete view in my mobile app that i am developing using Xamarin.

I have set threshold to 1 and set the focus to autocomplete view in onCreate event of activity.

```
autoCompleteView.FocusChange += delegate(object sender, View.FocusChangeEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.HasFocus)
    {
        autoCompleteView.ShowDropDown();
    } 
};
```

It displays the dropdown with all the suggestions when my app is loaded. Whenever i type text, it filters based on condition and everything is working fine. But when i clear all the text in the autocomplete view, the dropdown is closed. But i want to display the dropdown with all the suggestions.

Also whenever i touch/click the autocomplete view, the dropdown is closed. So i have added the below code to display the dropdown, but there is a flicker(dropdown is closed and is opened again).

```
autoCompleteView.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    autoCompleteView.ShowDropDown ();
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> It displays the dropdown with all the suggestions when my app is
>   loaded

1. You can call `autoCompleteView.ShowDropDown();` in you `OnCreate` (independant of focus), this way the app loads with the dropdown showing.

> Also whenever i touch/click the autocomplete view, the dropdown is
>   closed. So i have added the below code to display the dropdown, but
>   there is a flicker(dropdown is closed and is opened again).

2. Subscribe to the `TextChanged` event and call `autoCompleteView.ShowDropDown();` whenever the text in the `EditText` is `String.Empty`.

Comment: If i call autoCompleteView.ShowDropDown() OnCreate it throws an exception. Also, i have created a custom AutocompleteView that inherits AutoCompleteView and have overridden the EnoughToFilter method to return true always. By that even though i clear all the text, dropdown is not closed.

Comment: Still whenever i touch/click the autocompleteView, the dropdown is closed. Any help on this would be great!!!